# How do I add app to share menu for iOS/Android

Tags: react-native, ios-sharesheet, react-native-share, android-sharesheet

I'm trying to add my app to the list of available shares for other apps, and I wanted to make sure I had it right. The documentation doesn't explicitly state this, and I *really* want to be sure of what it means before I move forward:

Every app that wants *other* apps to share to them needs to add their app to the Share Extension, correct?

I.E. if I want to share to *another* app, they would have to make the requisite changes on *their* app so that it would be listed in the list of available apps to share to, correct?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm faced with the same challenge

Comment: Yes. You use a package (like react-native-share) to add your app to the share sheet. This will make it available to other apps that utilize that functionality. :) https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share